# How to hint that a variable is a class inheriting from another class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

Consider this contrived code snippet:

```
class Fooer():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do things

    def foo(self) -> int:
        # do more things

def foo(fooer, *args, **kwargs) -> int:
    return x(*args, **kwargs).foo()
```

I want to hint that the `fooer` argument to `foo()` should be a subclass of `Fooer`. It's not an instance of `Fooer`, it's either `Fooer` itself or a subclass thereof. The best I could think of was

```
def foo(fooer: type, *args, **kwargs) -> int
```

which isn't specific enough.

How can I hint this better?

Comment: Subclassing is bad.  Don't encourage it in your APIs.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone i'm attempting to clean up an existing codebase. This is mostly for my sanity and the sanity of my teammates. Also there are plenty of valid, and/or practical reasons to use subclassing, despite the recent (justified, but overblown) anti-inheritance meme.

Comment: @chepner `fooer` is not an instance of `Fooer`, it's a class, either `Fooer` itself or a subclass thereof

Comment: Ah, that is a crucial detail I missed.

Comment: If I'm reading PEP-484 correctly, I think it's `fooer: Type[Fooer]`.

Comment: @chepner yep that's the answer! https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type Post it so I can give you the +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From PEP-484 ([The type of class objects](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#the-type-of-class-objects)), the solution is to use `Type[C]` to indicate subclasses of `C`, where `C` is a type var bounded by your base class.

```
F = TypeVar('F', bound=Fooer)

def foo(fooer: Type[F], *args,**kwargs) -> int:
    ...
```

(To be fair, I don't quite get the difference between using the `TypeVar` here, as indicated by PEP-484, versus using the class itself as in @e.s.'s answer.)

Answer (score 2):

there a `Type` in `typing`

```
from typing import Type

class A(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing

class B(A):
    pass

def make_it(a_class: Type[A]):
    return a_class(3)

make_it(B)  # type checks ok
make_it(str)  # type checks complaining
```